# Slow printing - still need answers

Tags: python, python-2.7

This topic has already been covered but I am still having trouble. The code I have does print the string but it prints it extremely fast. I have tried changing the time value but it doesn't seem to change anything.

Here is *everything* I have - Maybe I just need a more complete example?

```
import sys,time,random

typing_speed = 50 #wpm
def slow_type(t):
    for l in t:
        sys.stdout.write(l)
        time.sleep(random.random()*10.0/typing_speed)
print "Tell if you think this is too fast?"
```

Comment: In your example, you define a function and print a string. Of course it'll be fast. You should at least call your function before printing

Comment: Try `slow_type("Tell if you think this is too fast?")`.

Comment: You never used `slow_type`!

Comment: You forgot to flush after each write.

Answer (score 3):

```
import sys,time,random

typing_speed = 50 #wpm

def slowprint(t):
    for l in t:
        sys.stdout.write(l)
        sys.stdout.flush() # Forcing the output of everything in the buffer. 
        time.sleep(random.random()*10.0/typing_speed)

    sys.stdout.write("\n") # Printing a newline, because it looks cleaner.

slowprint ("Tell if you think this is too fast?")
```

I changed the name of the function because `slowprint` seem a little more explicit in my opinion.

I like the following version better - it accepts an argument to control the speed.

```
import sys,time,random

def slowprint(t, s): # s is the typing speed - formally held in `typing_speed`
    for l in t:
        sys.stdout.write(l)
        sys.stdout.flush() # Forcing the output of everything in the buffer. 
        time.sleep(random.random()*10.0/s)

    sys.stdout.write("\n") # Printing a newline, because it looks cleaner.

slowprint ("Tell if you think this is too fast?", 50)
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem with the existing solution(s) is I don't see how the code coerces the output to the stated WPM except by trial and error:

```
time.sleep(random.random()*10.0/typing_speed)
```

and seems to get it wrong, time-wise, by more than 2X too fast.

If instead we use the standard definition of *word* in WPM as "five keystrokes" and the standard definition of *minute* in WPM as "sixty seconds", then "Tell if you think this is too fast?" should take ~ 8.5 seconds.  Reworking the code using the above logic, we get something like:

```
import sys
import time

typing_speed = 50  # wpm

def slowprint(string):

    # the WPM system considers a word to be 5 keystrokes
    # so convert from words per minute to seconds per character
    spc = 12.0 / typing_speed  # 12.0 = 60 seconds per minute / 5 characters per word

    for character in string:
        sys.stdout.write(character)
        sys.stdout.flush()  # Force the output of everything in the buffer.

        time.sleep(spc)

    sys.stdout.write("\n")  # print a newline, because it looks cleaner.

slowprint("Tell if you think this is too fast?")
```